# How to solve Apache2 error "(32)Broken pipe: core_output_filter: writing data to the network"

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, wordpress

The index.php file of our companies Wordpress(3.5.1, a handfull visitors per day) blog reacts very lame to each request. It appears after a minute. This behaviour comes out of the blue, no changes where made to the system.

Looking at the apache 2 error.log file, i found the following:

```
(32) Broken pipe: core_output_filter: writing data to the network
```

Searching in the internet i found already one possible solution for the problem. It was mentioned that it'll help to add

```
EnableSendfile Off
```

to httpd.conf, but nothing changes.